# I'm installing rocky linux 8.9 in my virtual box But, there is a problem

Tags: dependencies, centos, janus-gateway, rocky-os

I want to install janus-gateway on my rocky-linux 8.9
So, I will need to satisfy the following dependencies.

I'm installing it watching github.
When I try to install sofia-sip-level, libconfig-level, I can't install it.

dnf install sofia-sip-devel libconfig-devel

Please tell me how to install it.

install sofia-sip-devel, libconfig-devel